# Can I make Vim's fold indicators visually subtler?

Tags: vim

Fold indicators in vim are prominent because they take up the entire window width:

```
  void foo() {
+--- 10 lines: int x;-----------------------------------------------------------
  }
```

which makes them distracting. Something like the following would be better:

```
  void foo() {
    [10 lines: int x;]
  }
```

Is this achievable in vim?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's definitely possible.  See (the single quotes are meant to be typed):

```
:help 'foldtext'
```

For example:

```
function! MyFoldText()
    let lines = printf('%' . len(line('$')) . 'd', v:foldend - v:foldstart + 1)
    let line  = substitute(foldtext(), '^+-\+ *\d\+ lines: ', '', '')

    return '[' . lines . ' lines: ' . line . ']'
endfunction

set foldtext=MyFoldText()
```